# network-bsd hidden hence not found

Tags: windows, haskell, package, cabal

I am trying to install uni-htk in Windows but getting following error:

```
Util\HostName.hs:8:1: error:
    Could not load module `Network.BSD'
    It is a member of the hidden package `network-bsd-2.8.1.0'.
    Perhaps you need to add `network-bsd' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
8 | import Network.BSD
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As mentioned in error above, network-bsd is installed but hidden. I cannot find any .cabal file where I could make changes.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

`uni-htk` has not been updated to work with newer versions of libraries (i.e. it is bitrotted, with last version in 2016). If you `cabal unpack uni-htk` you can get a local directory with all the source, and edit its `cabal` file and otherwise to fix it up yourself.

(This particular error is because the `Network.BSD` module has been moved from the `network` package to the new `network-bsd` package, I think. But you'll probably hit other errors as well!)